# How to download all files in a link

Tags: file, download

I have this link

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/crunch/

which has many files in it.

I tried to download it through FileZilla but did not work. it is not ftp

so how can I download all files in that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use any "SVN client" to *checkout* the repository at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/crunch

Try with Tortoise SVN for windows https://tortoisesvn.net/ or any svn client listed in https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Using SVN from command line you can get the complete repository running:

```
svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/crunch
```

And then you can compress the retrieved 'crunch' folder if you want.